# WPF, specific text height

Tags: c#, wpf, text, measurement

I'd like to measure and then draw some text in my custom control, but I'd like it to have specific height *in pixels*. How do I do that?

Comment: did you try putting your `TextBlock` inside `ViewBox` with set height?

Comment: I can't. I want to *measure* and *draw* the text, not compose my control from other ones. (Draw = `OnRender`)

Comment: measurement of text height includes the full font metrics, so it is not easy to have exact pixel size as it may differ font to font. see [Font Metrics and Drawing Strings](http://www.harmless.de/cocoa-other.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`GlyphRun` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.glyphrun%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to provide detailed control over text composition. From the linked page:

> Represents a sequence of glyphs from a single face of a single font at a single size, and with a single rendering style.

For beginners, please see the [Introduction to the GlyphRun Object and Glyphs Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748985%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page in MSDN, but if you want to jump straight in, please read the [GlyphRun and So Forth](http://smellegantcode.wordpress.com/2008/07/03/glyphrun-and-so-forth/) page from the Smellegant Code website to find out one way to measure the text. The crucial part from the last linked page goes like this:

```
double totalWidth = 0;

for (int n = 0; n < text.Length; n++)
{
    ushort glyphIndex = glyphTypeface.CharacterToGlyphMap[text[n]];
    glyphIndexes[n] = glyphIndex;

    double width = glyphTypeface.AdvanceWidths[glyphIndex] * size;
    advanceWidths[n] = width;

    totalWidth += width;
}
```